# Assembly, the meaning behind the colon ":"

Tags: assembly, tasm

I'm new to assembly and I'm currently reading a guide that would frequently express things like `ax:bx`, `ds:dx`, `ss:sp`.

I'll use one of the above in an example from the book "Mastering Turbo Assembly" Page 85.

> Notice that the logical address in ss:sp points to the byte below the last byte in the stack.

What is the meaning of the `:` notation?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 6):

Those are memory addresses expressed in the segment:offset scheme. See e.g. http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html

Comment: At least for `segreg:reg` pairings. In some contexts you'd use `:` simply to denote a pair of registers, e.g. when you use `DIV`/`IDIV` with a 16-bit operand you're dividing the 32-bit register pair `DX:AX` by the value of the operand.

Comment: A short answer with a powerful huge information. THANKS, this information is GOLD